# transport security being required come 2017, will a link in an app that opens a non-https site in safari be acceptable?

Tags: ios, http, https, ios10, app-transport-security

When ATS is officially executed (with no exceptions) in January 2017, will I be able to leave a non-https website link in an app that is allowed to be opened by safari rather than in an in-browser app?  Or is this practice also unacceptable?

Is there any way to maintain reference to a non-https site once this change takes place?  Or is this practice DOA?

Comment: Only Apple can answer this question, but they have stated that they will allow exceptions to ATS where justified.  In my opinion they are going to have to be reasonable as there are a large number of sites that will never move to HTTPS.  One of my apps supports embedded devices that will never support HTTPS and even if they did user's wouldn't go to the trouble of installing certificates

Comment: Would you happen to know if ATS is enabled automatically in Xcode 8?

Comment: ATS is enabled automatically in any app compiled against the iOS9 SDK or later, so Xcode 7.3 and on

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Trying to cover my bases here, if I'm able to load a non-https site in safari, ATS shouldn't be a problem come January?

Comment: I don't believe that ATS applies to Safari.  Only to your in-app use of HTTP

Comment: So ATS really applies to in app-browsers/url requests?

Comment: See the update to my answer below. There is a new ATS exception that applies to the in-app browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Transport Security only affects server calls within the app.  If you are loading the URLs in Safari, you will be fine.  In fact, [here](http://blog.codiform.com/2016/01/opening-app-transport-security-failures.html) is a good tutorial for a developer who attempts to load pages in the UIWebView, but if it fails due to ATS, they load it in Safari instead.

One additional note is that you should consider using `SFSafariViewController` to open the URLs within your app, but with all of the benefits of opening in Safari.  `SFSafariViewController` allows arbitrary loads (meaning it doesn't enforce ATS), but it allows you to keep users within your app.  It's certainly worth considering if you are targetting iOS 9 and newer.

Also, your question has a bit of an incorrect statement in that ATS will be more strict starting in 2017, but there will still be exceptions allowed.  Certain media streams will not require ATS (because of the overhead of encryption on something like a video), as well as your apps can still request an exception from Apple, but it remains to be seen what Apple will deem a valid justification for exceptions.  Also, Apple will still be allowing apps to put in exceptions for the forward secrecy requirement of ATS.  So it's not quite as simple as your question states.

**Edit:**
It appears Apple has added a new exception you can use to allow non-ATS connections in `UIWebview` and `WKWebview` instances. It is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`. This should do exactly what you are looking for.  Here is a great summary of the latest with ATS: [preparing for ATS in 2017](https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2016/08/14/ats-enforced-2017/?utm_campaign=iOS%2BDev%2BWeekly&utm_medium=email&utm_source=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_266).

Comment: Ah, this is very interesting.  Do you have more information regarding sfsafariviewcontroller and urls without https signing? I'm looking to have an in-app browser that only loads one site (that is preset) but doesn't necessarily a "secure" site.

Comment: No need to worry about secure or non-secure browsing in the SFSafariViewController.  Just give it a URL and it is just like they were browsing in the Safari app.  Here's a tutorial: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/iOS-9-Tutorial-Series-SFSafariViewController